# Jinja2 extract substring from a list inside a template

Tags: python, jinja2

How do i extract a char substring from a mixed string within a template in Jinja2?

e.g. string is COW34, but i want to extract only COW

I'm importing a python dict inside a template and accessing the values as below

// ANIMAL_LIST = ["DOG", "CAT", "SHEEP0", "SHEEP1", "HORSE", "COW0", "COW1", "COW2"]

// Inside a Template i have this code

```
  {% for animal in import_features["ANIMAL_LIST"] -%}
       ##// I want to extract just the animal name from this list
      {{animal}}
  {% endfor %}

//I am getting this which is correct behavior
DOG
CAT
SHEEP0
SHEEP1
HORSE
COW0
COW1
COW2

//But i want this
DOG
CAT
SHEEP
SHEEP
HORSE
COW
COW
COW
```

Comment: where is dict as you mentioned?

Comment: can you index it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.